# MinIo Java cannot connect to s3 by https

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, web, minio

I ran into a problem connecting to MinIO over https.

If my backend server connects to MinIO via http, then everything is fine.
But when trying to connect via https, an error occurs:
"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

Java 11
MinIo-Java: 8.3.3

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'newsController' defined in file [/Users/mirrol/Desktop/sio_system/publication/build/classes/java/main/kg/sio/publication/controller/NewsController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newsService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is error occurred
ErrorResponse(code = SignatureDoesNotMatch, message = The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method., bucketName = publication, objectName = null, resource = /publication, requestId = 16F3C2EBD7CDABAA, hostId = f3d75ef8-2e98-461a-8f4a-d3e053bdcff4)
request={method=GET, url=https://s3.gso.kg/publication?location=, headers=Host: s3.gso.kg
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: MinIO (Mac OS X; x86_64) minio-java/8.3.3
Content-MD5: 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date: 20220530T030325Z
Authorization: ██
}
response={code=403, headers=Date: Mon, 30 May 2022 03:03:26 GMT
Server: nginx/1.21.3
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 381
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Security-Policy: block-all-mixed-content
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
X-Amz-Request-Id: 16F3C2EBD7CDABAA
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at kg.sio.publication.Application.main(Application.java:13) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newsService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is error occurred
ErrorResponse(code = SignatureDoesNotMatch, message = The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method., bucketName = publication, objectName = null, resource = /publication, requestId = 16F3C2EBD7CDABAA, hostId = f3d75ef8-2e98-461a-8f4a-d3e053bdcff4)
request={method=GET, url=https://s3.gso.kg/publication?location=, headers=Host: s3.gso.kg
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: MinIO (Mac OS X; x86_64) minio-java/8.3.3
Content-MD5: 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date: 20220530T030325Z
Authorization: ██
}
response={code=403, headers=Date: Mon, 30 May 2022 03:03:26 GMT
Server: nginx/1.21.3
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 381
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Security-Policy: block-all-mixed-content
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
X-Amz-Request-Id: 16F3C2EBD7CDABAA
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.minio.errors.ErrorResponseException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
    at io.minio.S3Base.execute(S3Base.java:645) ~[minio-8.3.3.jar:8.3.3]
    at io.minio.S3Base.getRegion(S3Base.java:669) ~[minio-8.3.3.jar:8.3.3]
    at io.minio.S3Base.execute(S3Base.java:444) ~[minio-8.3.3.jar:8.3.3]
    at io.minio.S3Base.executeHead(S3Base.java:703) ~[minio-8.3.3.jar:8.3.3]
    at io.minio.MinioClient.bucketExists(MinioClient.java:1120) ~[minio-8.3.3.jar:8.3.3]
    at kg.sio.publication.service.NewsService.initialize(NewsService.java:49) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Comment: where is the minio hosted?